# where clause using multiple conditions

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

```
Code1 | Code2 | Code3
----------------------
101| 102  | null 
101| null | null
102| 104  | null
```

The above is the table called DiagCodes

Select *
From
Where

Where condition should check all the three columns Code1, Code2 and Code3.

Result: return the rows that has only the codes IN (101, 102)

**So, where condition should return the first and second rows only**
Third row shouldn't be returned because it has 104 code.

How do I write the where clause to check this condition?

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect something like this to work:

```
select * from table
where
(Code1 is null or Code1 in (101, 102)) and
(Code2 is null or Code2 in (101, 102)) and
(Code3 is null or Code3 in (101, 102))
```